# Azure AD App Registration - Exchange API - Read Calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have the following permissions granted in my Azure AD App:

App:

```
Read calendars in all mailboxes
Read and write calendars in all mailboxes
Read calendars in all mailboxes
```

Delegated:

```
Read user and shared calendars
Read and write user and shared calendars
Read and write user calendars
Read user calendars
Read and write user and shared calendars
Read user and shared calendars
```

[Registration Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ6gjm.png)

I am successfully generating an Access Token like the following:

```cs
const string clientId = "my-client-id";
const string clientSecret = "my-secret"; // C
var tenant = "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com";

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenant}/oauth2/token");
var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credentials);
```

With that Access Token, I am trying to make  a basic request to `/CalendarView` passing the Bearer token header:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/my@email.com/calendarview?startDateTime=2017-11-12&endDateTime=2017-11-13
```

However, I keep receiving `Access Denied`. Are there additional permissions I need to set? Am I calling into the correct endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You don't include the body of the error response, but my guess is that you're hitting this because Exchange won't accept a token generated with a shared secret. Instead, you need to use a certificate-based assertion to request the token. Azure documents this a "Second case: Access token request with a certificate" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service#request-an-access-token).

Answer (score 1):

I actually was able to figure this out. Instead of using the Exchange API, I just applied the permissions in the Graph API.

Hit the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{email}/calendarview?startDateTime={startDate}&endDateTime={endDate}
```

It's not very clear the difference between which API to use... but I'm moving forward now.

Comment: Glad you solved it. The problem was you commingled a number of APIs: `Azure AD Graph`, `Microsoft Graph`, `Office 365 REST` and `Exchange Web Services` are distinct APIs with different permissions and patterns. In general, you want to stick with Microsoft Graph endpoints (`graph.microsoft.com`).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!